# Is Visual Studio 2013 Express (Update 3) supposed to have Windows Store Javascript templates?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013, windows-store-apps, windows-store

This page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh986964.aspx

would have you believe that "VS2013 Express for Windows" (Update 3) has support for javascript Windows Store apps. But when I try to create a new app there are no Javascript templates. Is this expected? Is the documentation wrong?

EDIT:

Ok, so I went to Add/Remove Programs, Selected "Visual Studio Express 2013 For Windows - ENU with Update 3" and ran a repair. It took about 20 minutes, but after that (and a reboot - not sure if that was really necessary, it was for an unrelated reason) the JavaScript templates are back...

Answer (score 0):

You can try download Microsoft Web Matrix from Microsoft Download Center. You will then be able to add a lot of different libraries for use in VS or VSE. I'm fairly certain there are a lot of JS libraries.

Comment: I don't think that gets you Windows Store support, just desktop.